# Streamlit.line_chart() auto-sorting displaying info in the wrong order when format is 'day/month/year'

Tags: python, linechart, streamlit

I'm using streamlit for a project, and I have this database.

```
{'29/04 16:42:23': 0, '29/04 17:21:07': 0, '14/05 04:45:48': 0, '14/05 06:24:14': 2.0, '14/05 06:24:39': 7.0, '14/05 06:25:09': 2.0, '14/05 06:25:24': 5.0, '14/05 06:25:40': 7.0, '14/05 06:25:56': 5.0, '15/05 21:38:50': 7.0, '15/05 21:39:05': 5.0, '15/05 21:39:20': 3.0, '15/05 21:39:37': 2.0, '15/05 21:39:54': 8.0, '15/05 21:40:09': 1.0, '15/05 21:40:24': 7.0, '15/05 21:40:40': 3.0, '15/05 21:40:55': 8.0, '15/05 21:41:10': 2.0, '17/05 18:31:47': 0, '17/05 18:32:31': 0, '17/05 18:33:14': 0, '17/05 18:33:31': 0, '17/05 18:34:07': 0, '17/05 18:34:38': 0, '17/05 18:34:56': 0, '17/05 18:35:12': 0, '17/05 18:35:28': 0, '17/05 18:36:35': 0, '17/05 18:36:56': 0, '17/05 18:37:13': 0, '17/05 18:37:43': 0, '17/05 18:37:59': 0, '17/05 18:38:16': 0, '17/05 18:38:32': 0, '17/05 18:38:53': 0, '17/05 18:39:12': 0, '17/05 18:39:32': 0, '17/05 18:39:48': 0, '17/05 18:40:04': 0, '17/05 18:40:23': 0, '17/05 18:40:50': 0, '17/05 18:41:16': 0, '17/05 18:41:39': 0, '17/05 18:41:54': 0, '17/05 18:42:11': 0, '17/05 18:42:28': 0, '17/05 18:42:48': 0, '17/05 18:44:18': 0, '17/05 18:44:39': 0, '17/05 18:45:25': 0, '17/05 18:45:41': 0, '17/05 18:46:00': 0, '17/05 18:46:16': 0, '17/05 18:46:39': 0, '17/05 18:47:00': 0, '17/05 19:23:24': 0, '28/06 23:53:01': 0, '10/08 20:09:01': 0, '10/08 20:42:03': 0, '10/08 20:42:23': 0, '10/08 20:42:56': 0, '10/08 20:43:16': 0, '10/08 20:43:36': 0, '10/08 20:43:57': 0, '10/08 20:44:17': 0, '10/08 20:44:37': 0, '10/08 20:45:17': 0, '10/08 20:45:38': 0, '10/08 20:45:58': 0, '10/08 20:46:18': 0, '10/08 20:46:39': 0, '18/08 01:56:18': 109.3, '18/08 01:56:40': 0, '21/08 23:51:09': 0, '21/08 23:51:31': 0, '27/08 08:28:08': 0, '27/08 08:28:37': 19.29, '27/08 08:28:58': 0, '27/08 08:29:18': 0, '27/08 08:29:38': 0, '27/08 08:29:59': 0, '27/08 08:30:19': 0, '27/08 08:30:39': 0, '27/08 08:31:00': 0, '27/08 08:33:35': 0, '27/08 08:33:55': 180.37, '27/08 08:34:16': 81.12, '27/08 08:34:35': 83.59, '27/08 08:34:55': 35.57, '27/08 08:35:16': 298.79, '28/08 03:52:26': 0, '28/08 03:52:47': 0, '28/08 03:53:07': 0, '28/08 03:53:27': 0, '28/08 03:53:49': 0, '28/08 03:54:09': 0, '28/08 03:54:29': 0, '28/08 03:54:49': 0, '28/08 03:55:10': 0, '28/08 03:55:30': 0, '28/08 03:55:50': 0, '28/08 03:56:11': 0, '28/08 03:56:31': 0, '28/08 03:56:51': 0, '28/08 03:57:11': 0, '28/08 03:57:32': 0, '28/08 03:57:52': 0, '28/08 03:58:13': 0, '28/08 03:58:34': 0, '28/08 04:22:52': 86.3, '28/08 04:23:12': 88.08, '28/08 04:23:32': 63.11, '28/08 04:23:52': 75.01, '28/08 04:24:13': 19.29, '28/08 04:24:33': 77.26, '28/08 04:24:53': 58.64, '28/08 04:25:13': 42.77, '28/08 04:25:34': 98.34, '28/08 04:25:54': 97.98, '28/08 04:26:14': 98.36, '28/08 04:26:35': 89.78, '28/08 04:26:55': 87.62, '28/08 04:45:17': 99.23, '28/08 04:45:38': 76.73, '28/08 04:50:34': 51.48, '28/08 04:50:55': 51.45, '28/08 04:51:15': 19.28, '28/08 04:51:38': 42.77, '28/08 10:37:41': 75.56, '28/08 10:38:03': 19.16, '28/08 10:38:25': 42.63, '28/08 10:38:46': 42.65, '28/08 11:55:16': 44.76, '28/08 11:55:39': 43.9, '28/08 11:55:59': 43.9, '28/08 11:56:21': 43.92, '28/08 11:56:42': 43.9, '28/08 11:57:03': 44.85, '28/08 11:57:23': 44.85, '28/08 11:57:44': 44.86, '28/08 11:58:06': 45.22, '28/08 11:58:25': 44.86, '28/08 11:58:48': 45.24, '28/08 11:59:08': 44.83, '28/08 11:59:29': 44.81, '28/08 11:59:51': 45.21, '28/08 12:00:12': 44.76, '28/08 12:00:32': 44.28, '28/08 12:00:55': 44.78, '28/08 12:01:16': 44.78, '28/08 12:01:36': 44.68, '28/08 12:01:57': 44.68, '28/08 12:02:19': 44.66, '28/08 12:02:41': 44.66, '28/08 12:03:02': 43.87, '28/08 12:03:23': 44.26, '28/08 12:03:44': 43.85, '28/08 12:04:05': 44.26, '28/08 12:04:26': 43.85, '28/08 12:04:48': 43.87, '28/08 12:05:08': 43.84, '28/08 12:05:30': 43.49, '28/08 12:05:52': 43.87, '28/08 12:06:13': 43.85, '28/08 12:06:34': 43.94, '28/08 12:06:56': 44.26, '28/08 12:07:17': 43.89, '28/08 12:07:38': 43.85, '28/08 12:08:00': 42.7, '28/08 12:08:21': 42.69, '28/08 12:08:42': 43.1, '28/08 12:09:04': 43.08, '28/08 12:09:25': 52.19, '28/08 12:09:46': 59.6, '28/08 12:10:05': 59.99, '28/08 14:42:42': 54.35, '28/08 14:43:03': 54.35, '28/08 14:43:25': 53.92, '28/08 14:43:46': 53.32, '28/08 14:44:05': 45.02, '28/08 14:44:26': 52.89, '28/08 14:44:48': 0, '28/08 14:45:11': 54.33, '28/08 14:45:32': 42.72, '28/08 14:45:53': 42.69, '28/08 14:46:14': 42.81, '28/08 14:46:35': 43.22, '28/08 14:46:56': 43.2, '28/08 14:47:17': 43.24, '28/08 14:47:38': 43.22, '28/08 14:48:00': 43.22, '28/08 14:48:21': 43.24, '28/08 14:48:43': 43.2, '28/08 14:49:04': 43.22, '28/08 14:49:25': 43.22, '28/08 14:49:47': 43.22, '28/08 14:50:06': 53.04, '28/08 14:50:27': 43.66, '28/08 14:50:48': 43.12, '28/08 14:51:09': 0, '28/08 14:51:29': 44.09, '28/08 14:51:51': 43.97, '01/09 12:40:58': 0, '01/09 12:41:23': 0, '01/09 12:41:45': 0, '01/09 12:42:08': 175.24, '01/09 12:42:30': 170.63, '01/09 12:42:52': 19.21, '01/09 12:43:19': 21.64, '01/09 12:43:41': 105.87, '01/09 12:44:03': 68.36, '01/09 12:44:26': 86.09, '02/09 15:59:22': 192.63, '02/09 16:00:48': 192.92, '02/09 16:01:09': 198.97, '02/09 16:01:38': 199.56, '02/09 16:02:02': 191.65, '02/09 16:02:27': 192.42, '02/09 16:03:32': 0, '02/09 16:04:23': 0, '02/09 16:05:00': 0, '02/09 16:05:23': 189.01, '02/09 16:05:49': 201.02, '03/09 02:52:17': 0, '03/09 02:52:44': 0, '03/09 02:53:09': 47.23, '03/09 02:53:30': 45.34, '03/09 02:53:46': 45.77, '03/09 02:54:08': 133.41, '03/09 02:54:30': 162.48, '03/09 02:55:06': 19.48, '03/09 02:55:27': 21.95, '03/09 02:55:48': 19.33, '03/09 02:56:09': 22.78, '03/09 02:56:29': 22.69, '03/09 02:56:50': 21.04, '03/09 02:57:10': 19.31, '03/09 02:57:31': 19.19, '03/09 02:58:07': 19.35, '03/09 02:58:28': 19.19, '03/09 02:59:19': 22.3, '03/09 02:59:40': 21.8, '03/09 03:00:00': 21.85, '03/09 03:00:21': 19.45, '03/09 03:00:42': 19.59, '03/09 03:01:02': 19.29, '03/09 03:01:23': 53.53, '03/09 03:01:44': 54.4, '03/09 03:02:05': 42.53, '03/09 03:02:26': 51.35, '03/09 03:02:47': 55.33, '03/09 03:03:08': 19.41, '03/09 03:03:29': 55.5, '03/09 03:03:50': 39.82, '03/09 03:04:11': 38.19, '03/09 03:04:32': 31.81, '03/09 03:04:53': 44.88, '03/09 03:05:13': 55.62, '03/09 03:05:35': 36.53, '03/09 03:05:55': 55.57, '03/09 03:06:17': 19.23, '03/09 03:06:37': 45.07, '03/09 03:06:58': 19.19, '03/09 03:07:19': 19.47, '03/09 03:07:40': 27.71, '03/09 03:08:00': 19.43, '03/09 03:08:21': 25.98, '03/09 03:08:41': 24.37, '03/09 03:10:02': 17.51, '03/09 03:10:19': 17.92, '03/09 03:10:39': 13.94, '03/09 03:11:00': 5.35, '03/09 03:11:20': 2.97, '03/09 03:11:41': 2.97, '03/09 03:12:01': 2.97, '03/09 03:12:22': 2.97, '03/09 03:12:43': 19.53, '03/09 03:13:19': 14.01, '03/09 03:13:55': 78.8, '03/09 03:14:47': 44.76, '03/09 03:15:08': 45.45, '03/09 03:15:29': 66.08, '03/09 03:16:20': 48.41, '03/09 03:16:56': 3.57, '03/09 03:17:47': 3.91, '03/09 03:18:08': 3.91, '03/09 03:18:28': 3.91, '03/09 03:18:49': 3.91, '03/09 03:19:09': 3.91, '03/09 03:19:29': 3.91, '03/09 03:19:50': 3.91, '03/09 03:20:10': 3.91, '03/09 03:20:31': 3.91, '03/09 03:21:22': 42.02, '03/09 03:21:42': 14.85, '03/09 03:50:32': 0, '03/09 03:51:27': 19.19, '03/09 03:52:04': 19.47
```

It is in chronologic order, but when I display it in streamlit line_chart, the x-axis order seems to change this order.

I tried modifying the data base, and messing with the amount of values, and it seems to be displaying it in the wrong order because of the auto-sorting that the line_chart() function has, because the days can be greater than the month numbers.
Is there any way to turn the auto-sorting off, or to display the database in the original order? Thanks.

[Whole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFLTe.png).

[Working, until a day that has greater value from previous month is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFLTe.png).

[When a day that has greater value from previous month is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFLTe.png).

Comment: do your dates not specify a year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that streamlit cannot recognize the format of your date strings. If the year is missing from your dates, you can add the year to each date, then put the full datetime strings into a dataframe along with the values, sort everything by the datetime to ensure the dataframe is sorted chronologically, and then pass the dataframe and columns to `st.line_chart`.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

data = {'29/04 16:42:23': 0, '29/04 17:21:07': 0, '14/05 04:45:48': 0, '14/05 06:24:14': 2.0, '14/05 06:24:39': 7.0, '14/05 06:25:09': 2.0, '14/05 06:25:24': 5.0, '14/05 06:25:40': 7.0, '14/05 06:25:56': 5.0, '15/05 21:38:50': 7.0, '15/05 21:39:05': 5.0, '15/05 21:39:20': 3.0, '15/05 21:39:37': 2.0, '15/05 21:39:54': 8.0, '15/05 21:40:09': 1.0, '15/05 21:40:24': 7.0, '15/05 21:40:40': 3.0, '15/05 21:40:55': 8.0, '15/05 21:41:10': 2.0, '17/05 18:31:47': 0, '17/05 18:32:31': 0, '17/05 18:33:14': 0, '17/05 18:33:31': 0, '17/05 18:34:07': 0, '17/05 18:34:38': 0, '17/05 18:34:56': 0, '17/05 18:35:12': 0, '17/05 18:35:28': 0, '17/05 18:36:35': 0, '17/05 18:36:56': 0, '17/05 18:37:13': 0, '17/05 18:37:43': 0, '17/05 18:37:59': 0, '17/05 18:38:16': 0, '17/05 18:38:32': 0, '17/05 18:38:53': 0, '17/05 18:39:12': 0, '17/05 18:39:32': 0, '17/05 18:39:48': 0, '17/05 18:40:04': 0, '17/05 18:40:23': 0, '17/05 18:40:50': 0, '17/05 18:41:16': 0, '17/05 18:41:39': 0, '17/05 18:41:54': 0, '17/05 18:42:11': 0, '17/05 18:42:28': 0, '17/05 18:42:48': 0, '17/05 18:44:18': 0, '17/05 18:44:39': 0, '17/05 18:45:25': 0, '17/05 18:45:41': 0, '17/05 18:46:00': 0, '17/05 18:46:16': 0, '17/05 18:46:39': 0, '17/05 18:47:00': 0, '17/05 19:23:24': 0, '28/06 23:53:01': 0, '10/08 20:09:01': 0, '10/08 20:42:03': 0, '10/08 20:42:23': 0, '10/08 20:42:56': 0, '10/08 20:43:16': 0, '10/08 20:43:36': 0, '10/08 20:43:57': 0, '10/08 20:44:17': 0, '10/08 20:44:37': 0, '10/08 20:45:17': 0, '10/08 20:45:38': 0, '10/08 20:45:58': 0, '10/08 20:46:18': 0, '10/08 20:46:39': 0, '18/08 01:56:18': 109.3, '18/08 01:56:40': 0, '21/08 23:51:09': 0, '21/08 23:51:31': 0, '27/08 08:28:08': 0, '27/08 08:28:37': 19.29, '27/08 08:28:58': 0, '27/08 08:29:18': 0, '27/08 08:29:38': 0, '27/08 08:29:59': 0, '27/08 08:30:19': 0, '27/08 08:30:39': 0, '27/08 08:31:00': 0, '27/08 08:33:35': 0, '27/08 08:33:55': 180.37, '27/08 08:34:16': 81.12, '27/08 08:34:35': 83.59, '27/08 08:34:55': 35.57, '27/08 08:35:16': 298.79, '28/08 03:52:26': 0, '28/08 03:52:47': 0, '28/08 03:53:07': 0, '28/08 03:53:27': 0, '28/08 03:53:49': 0, '28/08 03:54:09': 0, '28/08 03:54:29': 0, '28/08 03:54:49': 0, '28/08 03:55:10': 0, '28/08 03:55:30': 0, '28/08 03:55:50': 0, '28/08 03:56:11': 0, '28/08 03:56:31': 0, '28/08 03:56:51': 0, '28/08 03:57:11': 0, '28/08 03:57:32': 0, '28/08 03:57:52': 0, '28/08 03:58:13': 0, '28/08 03:58:34': 0, '28/08 04:22:52': 86.3, '28/08 04:23:12': 88.08, '28/08 04:23:32': 63.11, '28/08 04:23:52': 75.01, '28/08 04:24:13': 19.29, '28/08 04:24:33': 77.26, '28/08 04:24:53': 58.64, '28/08 04:25:13': 42.77, '28/08 04:25:34': 98.34, '28/08 04:25:54': 97.98, '28/08 04:26:14': 98.36, '28/08 04:26:35': 89.78, '28/08 04:26:55': 87.62, '28/08 04:45:17': 99.23, '28/08 04:45:38': 76.73, '28/08 04:50:34': 51.48, '28/08 04:50:55': 51.45, '28/08 04:51:15': 19.28, '28/08 04:51:38': 42.77, '28/08 10:37:41': 75.56, '28/08 10:38:03': 19.16, '28/08 10:38:25': 42.63, '28/08 10:38:46': 42.65, '28/08 11:55:16': 44.76, '28/08 11:55:39': 43.9, '28/08 11:55:59': 43.9, '28/08 11:56:21': 43.92, '28/08 11:56:42': 43.9, '28/08 11:57:03': 44.85, '28/08 11:57:23': 44.85, '28/08 11:57:44': 44.86, '28/08 11:58:06': 45.22, '28/08 11:58:25': 44.86, '28/08 11:58:48': 45.24, '28/08 11:59:08': 44.83, '28/08 11:59:29': 44.81, '28/08 11:59:51': 45.21, '28/08 12:00:12': 44.76, '28/08 12:00:32': 44.28, '28/08 12:00:55': 44.78, '28/08 12:01:16': 44.78, '28/08 12:01:36': 44.68, '28/08 12:01:57': 44.68, '28/08 12:02:19': 44.66, '28/08 12:02:41': 44.66, '28/08 12:03:02': 43.87, '28/08 12:03:23': 44.26, '28/08 12:03:44': 43.85, '28/08 12:04:05': 44.26, '28/08 12:04:26': 43.85, '28/08 12:04:48': 43.87, '28/08 12:05:08': 43.84, '28/08 12:05:30': 43.49, '28/08 12:05:52': 43.87, '28/08 12:06:13': 43.85, '28/08 12:06:34': 43.94, '28/08 12:06:56': 44.26, '28/08 12:07:17': 43.89, '28/08 12:07:38': 43.85, '28/08 12:08:00': 42.7, '28/08 12:08:21': 42.69, '28/08 12:08:42': 43.1, '28/08 12:09:04': 43.08, '28/08 12:09:25': 52.19, '28/08 12:09:46': 59.6, '28/08 12:10:05': 59.99, '28/08 14:42:42': 54.35, '28/08 14:43:03': 54.35, '28/08 14:43:25': 53.92, '28/08 14:43:46': 53.32, '28/08 14:44:05': 45.02, '28/08 14:44:26': 52.89, '28/08 14:44:48': 0, '28/08 14:45:11': 54.33, '28/08 14:45:32': 42.72, '28/08 14:45:53': 42.69, '28/08 14:46:14': 42.81, '28/08 14:46:35': 43.22, '28/08 14:46:56': 43.2, '28/08 14:47:17': 43.24, '28/08 14:47:38': 43.22, '28/08 14:48:00': 43.22, '28/08 14:48:21': 43.24, '28/08 14:48:43': 43.2, '28/08 14:49:04': 43.22, '28/08 14:49:25': 43.22, '28/08 14:49:47': 43.22, '28/08 14:50:06': 53.04, '28/08 14:50:27': 43.66, '28/08 14:50:48': 43.12, '28/08 14:51:09': 0, '28/08 14:51:29': 44.09, '28/08 14:51:51': 43.97, '01/09 12:40:58': 0, '01/09 12:41:23': 0, '01/09 12:41:45': 0, '01/09 12:42:08': 175.24, '01/09 12:42:30': 170.63, '01/09 12:42:52': 19.21, '01/09 12:43:19': 21.64, '01/09 12:43:41': 105.87, '01/09 12:44:03': 68.36, '01/09 12:44:26': 86.09, '02/09 15:59:22': 192.63, '02/09 16:00:48': 192.92, '02/09 16:01:09': 198.97, '02/09 16:01:38': 199.56, '02/09 16:02:02': 191.65, '02/09 16:02:27': 192.42, '02/09 16:03:32': 0, '02/09 16:04:23': 0, '02/09 16:05:00': 0, '02/09 16:05:23': 189.01, '02/09 16:05:49': 201.02, '03/09 02:52:17': 0, '03/09 02:52:44': 0, '03/09 02:53:09': 47.23, '03/09 02:53:30': 45.34, '03/09 02:53:46': 45.77, '03/09 02:54:08': 133.41, '03/09 02:54:30': 162.48, '03/09 02:55:06': 19.48, '03/09 02:55:27': 21.95, '03/09 02:55:48': 19.33, '03/09 02:56:09': 22.78, '03/09 02:56:29': 22.69, '03/09 02:56:50': 21.04, '03/09 02:57:10': 19.31, '03/09 02:57:31': 19.19, '03/09 02:58:07': 19.35, '03/09 02:58:28': 19.19, '03/09 02:59:19': 22.3, '03/09 02:59:40': 21.8, '03/09 03:00:00': 21.85, '03/09 03:00:21': 19.45, '03/09 03:00:42': 19.59, '03/09 03:01:02': 19.29, '03/09 03:01:23': 53.53, '03/09 03:01:44': 54.4, '03/09 03:02:05': 42.53, '03/09 03:02:26': 51.35, '03/09 03:02:47': 55.33, '03/09 03:03:08': 19.41, '03/09 03:03:29': 55.5, '03/09 03:03:50': 39.82, '03/09 03:04:11': 38.19, '03/09 03:04:32': 31.81, '03/09 03:04:53': 44.88, '03/09 03:05:13': 55.62, '03/09 03:05:35': 36.53, '03/09 03:05:55': 55.57, '03/09 03:06:17': 19.23, '03/09 03:06:37': 45.07, '03/09 03:06:58': 19.19, '03/09 03:07:19': 19.47, '03/09 03:07:40': 27.71, '03/09 03:08:00': 19.43, '03/09 03:08:21': 25.98, '03/09 03:08:41': 24.37, '03/09 03:10:02': 17.51, '03/09 03:10:19': 17.92, '03/09 03:10:39': 13.94, '03/09 03:11:00': 5.35, '03/09 03:11:20': 2.97, '03/09 03:11:41': 2.97, '03/09 03:12:01': 2.97, '03/09 03:12:22': 2.97, '03/09 03:12:43': 19.53, '03/09 03:13:19': 14.01, '03/09 03:13:55': 78.8, '03/09 03:14:47': 44.76, '03/09 03:15:08': 45.45, '03/09 03:15:29': 66.08, '03/09 03:16:20': 48.41, '03/09 03:16:56': 3.57, '03/09 03:17:47': 3.91, '03/09 03:18:08': 3.91, '03/09 03:18:28': 3.91, '03/09 03:18:49': 3.91, '03/09 03:19:09': 3.91, '03/09 03:19:29': 3.91, '03/09 03:19:50': 3.91, '03/09 03:20:10': 3.91, '03/09 03:20:31': 3.91, '03/09 03:21:22': 42.02, '03/09 03:21:42': 14.85, '03/09 03:50:32': 0, '03/09 03:51:27': 19.19, '03/09 03:52:04': 19.47}
dates_with_year = [d.replace(' ', '/2023 ') for d in data.keys()]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': dates_with_year,
    'y': data.values()
})

df['x'] = pd.to_datetime(df['x'])
df = df.sort_values(by='x')

st.line_chart(
    df,
    x='x',
    y='y',
)
```

[image]

Comment: It does work for the "month/day/year" format, but not quite for the "day/month/year" format, since the day from a previous month can be higher than the day of the current or next months. But thanks for the solution.

Comment: And by the way, I figured out it seems to be happening because of auto-sorting in the line_chart() function.